# Set default file urls in angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am using angularjs file uploader given at "https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload", so my js code look like this:

```
var urls = ['url1', 'url2'];
var uploaders = $scope.uploaders = urls.map(function(url) {
    return new FileUploader({url: url});
});

$http.get('url.php').then(function(resp) {
   $scope.images = resp.data.images; // images array
   uploaders[0].addToQueue($scope.images[0]); 
  // add first img to 1st uploader
   var i;
   for(i=1;i<$scope.images.length;i++){ 
      uploaders[1].addToQueue($scope.images[i]); 
   }
   // append other images to 2nd uploader

});
```

Now I can get **uploaders[0].queue.length = 1** but not the other proerties like **uploaders[0].queue[0].file.name** ,
any suggestions?

Comment: So, are your images in `images` (local variable), or in `$scope.product.images`? Post your real code.

Comment: now in $scope.images...

Comment: Post your real code, the complete stack trace of the error, and tell us which line of code the stack trace refers to.

Comment: if you can suggest enqueue a file into a simple single file-Uploader then that will also be fine.

Comment: So, the error you got is not at all the one you posted in your question, in fact. Don't post that in the comments. Use the **non-minified** version of angular-file-upload, reproduce the error, and post it in the question. Using the non-minified version will make the location much more obvious, and will allow you to debug the code.

Comment: Hey, JB Nizet, I have correct the error issues but still uploader don't give info like file name.